# trying to make HTTP get request work on swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, request

I am relatively new to `swift`. As for now, I need to display the mysql datas to `table view` in my app. I have already prepared by `json` data which looks like

```
[{"restaurantnames":"restaurant 1","type":"type 1","location":"location 1"},{"restaurantnames":"restaurant 2","type":"type 1","location":"location 1"}]
```

Now I need to read `json` response and and populate my table view with these datas on app launch. For now, I have populated my `table rows` with the static data.  I am trying to make use of [this](https://github.com/daltoniam/JSONJoy-Swift) module for the `GET` request. This my `RestaurantViewController.swift`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/restaurant/registeruser.php")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        request.timeoutInterval = 60

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData!, respone:NSURLResponse!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil!) as? NSDictionary


            }



        })        

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are using, what is happening and any specific issues or questions you have.

Comment: Like Paulw11 said make the question specific. If it means you are not able to call the server than check out for ATS (App Transport Security) which blocks http calls while only allowing https call.

Comment: You can use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {     

    var restName:Array< String > = Array < String >()
    var restType:Array< String > = Array < String >()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
         get_data_from_url("http://localhost:8888/restaurant/registeruser.php")
     }

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }


   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return restName.count
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cellIdentifier = "CategoryTableViewCell"
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell

       cell.categoryName.text = restName[indexPath.row]
       cell.Name.text = restType[indexPath.row]

       return cell
   }


   func get_data_from_url(url:String) {


      var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!

      var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
      request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
      request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
      request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


      var reponseError: NSError?
      var response: NSURLResponse?

      var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)


       if  urlData != nil && reponseError == nil {

        let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        //NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300) {

            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            //NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            extract_json(urlData!)


        } else {
            var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Connection Failed"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()
        }


    } else {
        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
        alertView.message = "Connection Failure"
        if let error = reponseError {
            alertView.message = (error.localizedDescription)
        }
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    }



}

 func extract_json(data:NSData) {

    var error: NSError?

    let jsonData: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error)

    if (error == nil) {
        if let rest_cat_list = jsonData as? NSArray
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < rest_cat_list.count ; i++ )
            {
                if let rest_obj = rest_cat_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let restaurant = rest_obj["restaurantnames"] as? String
                    {
                       restName.append(restaurant)

                        if let restType = rest_obj["type"] as? String
                        {
                           restType.append(restType)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
     }
      do_table_refresh();
   }

 func do_table_refresh() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
  }
}
```

First go to this site and validate your URL

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog ( GOOGLE extenstion )

then replace below given values according to your settings  :-

```
      request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
      request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```